# Need to filter XML files based on XML attribute AND list the LastWriteTime

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have this relatively straightforward script to list a directory of approx. 2000 XML files, and I wish to limit the list to those with a specific attribute node called `Order`, with a value of `'2017-01-10'`.

While I can achieve this, I also need the `LastWriteTime` of the matching file.

So here is the result when returning the files (limited the result to just one):

```
PS> gci $path 

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------
-a---          1/9/2017  12:39 PM       6643 File.xml
```

And then using XPath to retrieve the node value:

```
PS> gci $path | Select-Xml -XPath "//Order[contains(@OrderDate,'2017-01-10')]"

Node        Path                    Pattern
----        ----                    -------
Order       \\<Path>\file.xml       //Order[contains(@OrderDate,'2017-01-10')]
```

But I need to combine the two scripts, so that I have the list of files only with the required node value, but also showing the `LastWriteTime`. It doesn't seem to like adding a `Select LastWriteTime` within the same line as the `Select-Xml`. Almost as if I'm using a "Where-Xml" if it existed.

Comment: Post your code please. We will work on that then .

Comment: Can you pipe to another `select` with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for `LastWriteTime`?

Comment: The code is exactly as posted. I'm looking to return the results that look the same as from the first script, except that this has filtered out all other files where the OrderDate does not match the specified date.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, BenH - I only get Node, Path and Pattern - how can I get the LastWriteTime property from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a particular property from an upstream object to the output of `Select-Xml` you can do so with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object {
  $file = $_
  Select-Xml -Path $file.FullName -XPath "//Order[contains(@OrderDate,'2017-01-10')]" |
    Select-Object -Property *,@{n='LastWriteTime';e={$file.LastWriteTime}}
}
```

Or you could create a custom object with just the properties you need:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object {
  $node = Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath "//Order[contains(@OrderDate,'2017-01-10')]"

  $prop = [ordered]@{
    FullName      = $_.FullName
    LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
    Node          = $node.Node
  }
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $prop
}
```

Or (if you actually want the file list, not the node list, as output, just filtered by particular content of the files) you could run the `Select-Xml` in a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {
  Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath "//Order[contains(@OrderDate,'2017-01-10')]"
}
```

Comment: That's awesome - this is very useful for me - thanks